# How to build a XML from multiple input xmls

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, domparser

I have a scenario where  I have to create a master.xml from 500 different XMLs, given the following :

-Some structure in start and end is always same.
-The  is picked up from 500 xmls as it is and added a particular location in master.xml, sample has only 3
 will have the total number of  added.

So essentially other than the  and  everything else remains constant.

How can I do this in Java1.5??

Sample Xml :

```
 <SERVICESMSG>
        <LMSGHDR>
            <HDRINFO>
                <HDRVERSNBRID>V1.0</HDRVERSNBRID>
            </HDRINFO>
            <MSGATTRIBUTE>
                <MSGID>1</MSGID>
                <MSGREQ></MSGREQ>
                <MSGTYPE>REQUEST</MSGTYPE>
                <RESPREQIND>N</RESPREQIND>
            </MSGATTRIBUTE>
        </LMSGHDR>
        <SIGNONMESSAGE>
            <AUTHENTICATION>
                <USERID></USERID>
                <USERPASS></USERPASS>
            </AUTHENTICATION>
        </SIGNONMESSAGE>
        <DOCMSGREQ>
            <ARCHIVEITEM></ARCHIVEITEM>
            <FUNCTION></FUNCTION>
            <SEARCHINFOR>
                <MAXNUMBER />
            </SEARCHINFOR>
            <AUDITINFO>
                <DOCNUMBER>27</DOCNUMBER>
            </AUDITINFO>
            <DOCUMENTINFO>
                <CHILDDOCMETAINFO>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr1">
                        <VALUE>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr2">
                        <VALUE>083121</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr3">
                        <VALUE>2018-12-01</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr4">
                        <VALUE>1234567890</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr5">
                        <VALUE>12345</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr6">
                        <VALUE>123</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr7">
                        <VALUE>123456789</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr8">
                        <VALUE>123</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <DOCMETAINFO>
                        <DOCUMENTPARTMETAINFO>
                            <IDENTIFIER />
                            <TYPE>DOC</TYPE>
                            <DOCUMENTPART>879yutfgcvbhjnhgfhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj=</DOCUMENTPART>
                        </DOCUMENTPARTMETAINFO>
                    </DOCMETAINFO>
                </CHILDDOCMETAINFO>
            </DOCUMENTINFO>
            <DOCUMENTINFO>
                <CHILDDOCMETAINFO>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr1">
                        <VALUE>12345678901234577777773456789012345678901234567890</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr2">
                        <VALUE>083222</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr3">
                        <VALUE>2018-12-01</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr4">
                        <VALUE>1234567890</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr5">
                        <VALUE>12345</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr6">
                        <VALUE>123</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr7">
                        <VALUE>123456789</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr8">
                        <VALUE>123</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <DOCMETAINFO>
                        <DOCUMENTPARTMETAINFO>
                            <IDENTIFIER />
                            <TYPE>DOC</TYPE>
                            <DOCUMENTPART>cvfegvieuriygfuergyfiuer7t89347598345555555555555555555555555555677</DOCUMENTPART>
                        </DOCUMENTPARTMETAINFO>
                    </DOCMETAINFO>
                </CHILDDOCMETAINFO>
            </DOCUMENTINFO>
            <DOCUMENTINFO>
                <CHILDDOCMETAINFO>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr1">
                        <VALUE>fcdsvgregvyeityi43ytfie43</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr2">
                        <VALUE>083222</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr3">
                        <VALUE>2018-12-01</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr4">
                        <VALUE>1234567890</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr5">
                        <VALUE>12345</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr6">
                        <VALUE>123</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr7">
                        <VALUE>123456789</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE ID="attr8">
                        <VALUE>123</VALUE>
                    </ATTRIBUTE>
                    <DOCMETAINFO>
                        <DOCUMENTPARTMETAINFO>
                            <IDENTIFIER />
                            <TYPE>DOC</TYPE>
                            <DOCUMENTPART>cvfegvieuriygfuergyfiuer7t89347598345555555555555555555555555555677</DOCUMENTPART>
                        </DOCUMENTPARTMETAINFO>
                    </DOCMETAINFO>
                </CHILDDOCMETAINFO>
            </DOCUMENTINFO>
        </DOCMSGREQ>
    </SERVICESMSG>
```

Comment: *"How can I do this in Java1.5??"* By writing some code that parses the input XMLs and writes the XML back out, using SAX or StAX parsers / formatters.

Comment: But I need same tag many times.. any sample code would be helpful

Comment: I thought you were merging multiple XML documents, not repeating the same XML over and over again. --- Sample code for what *specifically*? I bet, any specific area you want a sample for, is already available if you simply search for it.

Comment: I did serach but couldn't understand ! Since the xml iam handling a complex as comapred to examples in tutorial examples....

Comment: What couldn't you understand? How to parse XML in Java? How to write XML in Java? What ***specifically*** didn't you understand from the gazillion examples on the web showing you exactly how to do either of those?

Answer (score 0):

I was potentially new and couldn't understand the examples straight!
However, did it by creating a string and converting to xml using DOM parser. 
after which i validate it with a xsd.